# Convert adjacency matrix to array of edges

Tags: python

I want to be able to convert an adjacency matrix to array of edges. Currently I know only how to conver an array of edges to adjacency matrix:

```
E = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 0]]
size = len(set([n for e in E for n in e]))
adjacency_matrix = [[0] * size for _ in range(size)]
for sink, source in E:
    adjacency_matrix[sink][source] = 1
>> print(adjacency_matrix)
[[1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

but is there a possibility to reverse this process?

Comment: Do you have to use pure python or can you use numpy/networkx/…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need pure python, use a list comprehension:

```
adjacency_matrix = [[1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]]

E = [[i,j] for i,l in enumerate(adjacency_matrix) for j, x in enumerate(l) if x]
```

output: `[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 0]]`

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
E = np.stack(np.where(adjacency_matrix)).T
```

Add `tolist()` if you want a list

**Output** (with `tolist())`

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 0]]
```

**EDIT**: my bad I thought OP was using `numpy`, so here it is in numpy

Comment: A numpy solution is natural. +1

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible and easy, just iterate through your matrix using two nested cycles, for example:

```
adjacency_matrix = [[1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
E = []

for i in range(size):
    for j in range(size):
        if adjacency_matrix[i][j] == 1:
            E.append([i, j])

print(E)
```

**Output:**

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a function for it:

```
def adj_to_edges(A):
    edges = []
    for i,row in enumerate(A):
        for j,b in enumerate(row):
            if b == 1:
                edges.append([i,j])
    return edges

print(adj_to_edges([[1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]]))
#[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 0]]
```